# Should I close a connection that came from a datasource?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

When I do a dataSource.getConnection(), when I want the connection to be return to the pool (and not closed), does calling the close method return the connection to the pool or actually close it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call the close() on connection returned by a DataSource, it would return that to the pool to be used by other thread. Closing the connection defeats the purpose of the pool.

Comment: Why do you said : "Closing the connection defeats the purpose of the pool."  If closing the connection return it to the pool, it should be the expected behavior?

Comment: I meant to say if close() actually closes the PHYSICAL connection to the DB then there is no point in pooling connections.

Comment: What will happen to any pending transactions in the connection that have not been committed to the database? Does the datasource makes sure to commit pending transactions before returning the connection to the pool?

Comment: i can't understand? should i call close() or not?!

Comment: Yes, you should. When closing a connection obtained from a DataSource it will be automatic pooled.